# Diffrence between host and baseurl in ktor

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I am not able to completely understand the difference between `host` and `baseUrl` in ktor. I need to set a baseURL for my project and I have been through [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-730) and [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-759) youtrack issues but both of them suggests a little different approach and I confused what to choose. I can set `host = "baseurl"` in `defaultrequest` and then simply use

```
httpClient.post<T> {
    url("suffix here")
}
```

and it works. But am not sure if this is this the correct way and if it is then does it mean host works same as baseURL which we have in retrofit and okhttp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing works because of the way that `URLBuilder.takeFromUnsafe()` is implemented. This function is responsible for parsing your `"suffix here"` value into a url - it does so by setting only the portions of the url that it can identify in the string you're passing in. See `URLParser.kt#28` for more details.

Is it safe - yes. Is it a good idea? I don't think so. It's implicit and relies on future developers being familiar with the baseUrl approach used by other libraries (okhttp and retrofit).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the clarifying. no sure what should i use then any suggestions ? I have seen some live apps which uses `url($baseUrl\suffixhere)` but it doesn't seem like a good idea to me